# extract context function in salt stack

Tags: salt-stack

When looking at context, I notice one of my variable has

In my state file I have

```
{% set status = salt['service.get_all'] %}
```

When I dump the context I see,

```
"Context {'status': <function get_all at 0x036E9B30>, } "
```

How can I extract the values of 'status' if its a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to add the parenthesis

```
{% set status = salt['service.get_all'] () %}
```